# App crashes when adding Hamburger Icon on Toolbar

Tags: android, android-studio

Im adding a Hamburger Icon on the lesft side of my ToolBar but when Im running it the app crashes

Here is my xml file

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Test"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- Real content goes here -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:text="Test"/>
        </FrameLayout>

        <!-- The navigation drawer -->
        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and here is my java class

```
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class test extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout sideBar;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle sideBarToggle;
    private Toolbar actionToolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        /* Side Bar */
        actionToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(actionToolbar);
        sideBar = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        sideBarToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, sideBar,  R.string.Open, R.string.Close);
        sideBar.addDrawerListener(sideBarToggle);
        sideBarToggle.syncState();
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    }
}
```

Does it have any conflict with my custom Toolbar?

I dont know whats wrong and Im trying to search everywhere but still no luck. I dont know what or where to fix. thnx for the future help

Updated

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Test"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18dp" />


        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Added style.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: `AppBarLayout` is not a `Toolbar`

Comment: what di I need to fix with it?

Comment: Add `Toolbar` in `AppBarLayout `

Comment: @Opriday this is the current style Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar

Comment: @AntonA. please see my edited post

Comment: Go to style and set theme of NoActionBar then Add Toolbar Tag at the place AppBarLayout or Just remove TextView and add Toolbar inside AppBarLayout

Comment: @NardongBagsik Your update is totally wrong. Toolbarlayout should be within Appbarlayout and the theme shouldnt be NoActionBar

Comment: See my answer below. You didn't get my point. Kindly check my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**style.xml**

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**main_activity.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="im.opriday.customlistview.MainActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbr"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar instead of import android.widget.Toolbar

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbr);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Hello");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu_black_24dp);
}
```

[image]

Comment: sir this one is working the only thing i need to do is to hide open nav bar when i check it

Comment: I hope you can help me with that

Comment: For hiding nav bar you will have to add ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close)

Comment: I can't share full code in the comment section I will upload it on GitHub the soon will share with you. and If my answer help you then please vote up :)

Comment: This one did a great help all i need is the hide and show of toolbar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174660/discussion-between-opriday-and-nardong-bagsik).

Answer (score 0):

This code would be correct. No need in extra TextView

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

          <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
             android:id="@+id/toolbar"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have identifier(`android:id="@+id/toolbar"`) mentioned for the toolbar which you are referencing in your code. Since its not found it would return exception.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
   android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:id="@+id/toolbar"                 <!---missing-->
     android:layout_height="200dp">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Test"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:gravity="center"/>
  </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
 </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Your style.xml should have parent with ActionBar like `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar` and not NoActionBar as you have right now

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
```

Please follow this tutorial for guidance [link](https://medium.com/@tonia.tkachuk/appbarlayout-scroll-behavior-with-layout-scrollflags-2eec41b4366b)

Comment: added the code based on what you said please see the edited post still error

Comment: Whats the exception you are getting in the log?

Comment: @NardongBagsik Also your appbarlayout shouldn't have the `android:id="@+id/toolbar" ` as you have in code now. It should be in the toolbar

Comment: i found this earlier with my old codes `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`

Comment: Then remove the android:id="@+id/toolbar"  in the AppbarLayout. Thats the problem. The Toolbar should have android:id="@+id/toolbar"

Comment: I dont know the error occurs when I added the java code

Comment: @NardongBagsik Did u try the above?

Comment: Can you post the style.xml. Your app theme should have parent has someting with ActionBar. For eg:`@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar"`

Comment: @NardongBagsik sorry my bad...I corrected the style.xml

Answer (score 0):

Your layout must be in this order.

```
<DrawerLayout> 
  <AppBarLayout>
    <Toolbar>
   // Toolbar content
    </Toolbar>
  </AppBarLayout>
  <NavigationView />
</DrawerLayout>
```

You need to include the toolbar in your `ActionBarDraweToggle` constructor parameter if you want a default hamburger menu.

```
   sideBarToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, sideBar, actionToolbar , R.string.Open, R.string.Close);
```